# How to set CMake with Orocos-bfl in Ubuntu 18.04 - ROS Melodic

Tags: ros-melodic, ubuntu, ubuntu-bionic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am building a project that required the use of `Orocos-bfl`. I read official [documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/bfl) where it explains how to incluse `Orocos-bfl` into a `CMake` project. However without success. I also read this other [source](http://answers.ros.org/question/203209/orocos-bfl-for-indigo/) where it explains that it is not possible to build my own package against `BFL.`
So despite trying different options I cannot make my `CMake` compile the project with `Orocos-bfl` inside my `catkin_ws.` See below the project tree structure I have so far and that I am trying to compile:

```
--catkin_ws 
     --src
         -- project A
         -- project B
         --pf_localization (this is the project that should use `orocos-bfl`)
             --ros_float
             --config
             --include
             --launch
             --src
                  --pf_node.cpp (which is my executable file)
             --urdf
             --CMakeLists.txt
             --package.xml
```

I think that `CMake` is not accepting how I am setting the `orocos-bfl` and I am attaching below the `CMake` file I am trying to compile:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(ros_float)

## Compile as C++11, supported in ROS Kinetic and newer
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

find_package(rosbag REQUIRED)
include_directories(${rosbag_INCLUDE_DIRS})
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
  message_generation
)

find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(BFL REQUIRED orocos-bfl)
include_directories(${BFL_INCLUDE_DIRS}/bfl)
message("BFL include dirs:" ${BFL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
message("BFL library dirs:" ${BFL_LIBRARY_DIRS})

## Build ##

include_directories(
# include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

message(WARNING ${BFL_INCLUDE_DIRS})

file(GLOB INCLUDES
    "include/${PROJECT_NAME}/*.h"
    "include/${PROJECT_NAME}/*.cpp"
    "include/${PROJECT_NAME}/*.hpp"
    )

message(WARNING ${BFL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${BFL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_executable(pf_node src/pf_node.cpp ${INCLUDES})
target_link_libraries(pf_node ${BFL_LIBRARIES})
```

Also, just to cross off a possible doubts, I added `<build_depend>bfl</build_depend>` on my `package.xml` file

**The Error** of the compiler is below:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:452 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:622 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  pf_localization/ros_float/CMakeLists.txt:19 (pkg_check_modules)
```

Thank you for pointing in the right direction with this issue.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324737/how-to-set-cmake-with-orocos-bfl-in-ubuntu-18.04---ros-melodic/) by [RayROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/40704/rayros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2019-06-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found out the solution to my question for anyone that has/could have the same problem and wanted to share it.
After installing `orocos-bfl` from source for some reason that I still can't explain myself the `CMake` would not run and incur in continuous mistakes.

The solution was: `sudo synaptics` search for `orocos-bfl` and install it from there.

After restarting and updating no problems. So the `CMake` file I provided above is actually correct, but the installation had to be done from command line.
I hope this was useful if anyone incur in the same problem.

---

Originally posted by [RayROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/40704/rayros/) with karma: 108 on 2019-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0